# Filter array of objects as I type

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get this to work so that it returns the objects when I've only partially included the search string. Right now it only works if `val === 'Brady'` I'd like it to work if `val === 'B'` or `val === 'Ba'` etc.

```
const data = [{firstName: 'Brady',lastName: 'Smith'},{firstName: 'Jason',lastName: 'Brady'},{firstName: 'Michael',lastName: 'Bolten'}];

const filteredData = data.filter(data=>
     Object.values(data).some(val=> val === 'Brady')
)

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: `or val === 'Ba'` But `ba` is not contained in any of the strings..? Do you want a match if all characters are included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if a string is a substring.

> The `includes()` method determines whether one string may be found
>   within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.

```js
const data = [{
  firstName: 'Brady',
  lastName: 'Smith'
}, {
  firstName: 'Jason',
  lastName: 'Brady'
}, {
  firstName: 'Michael',
  lastName: 'Bolten'
}];

const search = "Br";
const filteredData = data.filter(data =>
  Object.values(data).some(val => {
    console.log(typeof val);
    return val.includes(search);
  })
)

console.log(filteredData)
```

Comment: I did this however I get `val.includes is not a function`

Comment: Maybe in that case the `val` variable is not a string. Can you give an example of that `val`?

Comment: Maybe try `val.toString().includes(search)`? This will work if you have numbers.

Comment: `console.log(Object.values(profile).some(val => val))` returns true/false

Comment: I edited my answer including the `console` for debugging. Please check and let me know what are you getting :)

Comment: Ok, my data set is much larger. It includes numbers as well. Why does this break it?

Comment: Yeah. numbers have no `includes` method. It is only for string and array. You can convert it by using `val.toString().includes(search)`

Comment: this will search '2' for 32304

Answer (score 0):

If you want a *start with* logic - you can try:

```
const filteredData = data.filter(data=>
 Object.values(data).some(val=> val.startWith(<your input value here>))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use String includes() method

```
const filteredData = data.filter(data=>
  Object.values(data).some(val=> val.includes("B") );
)
```